# Developing OpenShift cartridges that need large binaries

Tags: openshift

When developing an OpenShift cartridge, what is the standard way to handle large binaries that it will need? Let's say a 100 MB file. Searching around the web I saw a couple cartridges that had their required binaries in the git repository, but I thought that was generally considered to be a bad idea from a git perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add it to your repo as you mentioned or host the file elsewhere and wget it part of your install scripts.

Comment: If I go the wget route does OpenShift provide any way to cache the file for other apps?

Comment: Would you mind expanding on that a little more? I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: Downloading a 100 MB binary every time I create an application takes too long. Anyone using the cartridge would need the same binary, so I'm trying to figure out how to just download it once as a performance enhancement. The cartridge would check if the file exists locally, if it does then use it, if not or if it's changed then download it.